# How do I stop Excel from converting everything to date?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, cell-format

Every time I try to enter a fraction in Microsoft Excel 2010, it gets converted to a date.

So for example: 5.6 becomes 2013.05.06, and 5,6 becomes 1900.01.05  14:24:00. I do not want to format the cells as numbers, because then I have to set the number of decimal places. Either my integers will have ,00 at the end, or my floats get truncated.

How can I stop this behavior? Preferably, I'd like to disable this for Excel as a whole, rather than just for individual spreadsheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `'` before your value in the cell

Comment: While typing `'3/12` will prevent Excel from converting the fraction into a date, it does this by storing the value as plain text, meaning you can't do something like `='3/12`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Excel 2010 but I expect that formatting cells as "Text" will do the trick.

Comment: If I format the whole sheet as text, the functions will not be evaluated.

Comment: What I am looking for is most likely a checkbox in Options. Or at least is should be.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem (even after I set my decimal separator to comma)
but I have an answer for you to try.  What’s the greatest number of decimal digits
that you will ever want to display?  Let’s say it is four. 
Set a custom format on the cells where you will be entering numbers to `#,####`. 
Now, if you type `5,6`, it will be displayed as `5,6`, and if you type `5,642`,
it will be displayed as `5,642`.  At least that’s what it did on my machine (Excel 2007). 
The only drawback that I encountered is that, when I typed `5`, it was displayed as `5,`.